# Multithreading with Numpy Causes Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to generate a report that contains differing "groupings" of data. For each I have to query postgres differently and apply different logic, which can take a fair amount of time (~1 hour).

To increase performance I've created a thread for each task, each with its own connection as psycopg2 executes queries serially per connection. I'm using numpy to calculate the median and mean values of a portion of data (that is common between each group).

A short *example* of my code is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from postgres import Connection
from lookup import Lookup
from queries import QUERY1, QUERY2
from threading import Thread

class Report(object):

    def __init__(self, **credentials):
        self.conn = self.__get_conn(**credentials)
        self._lookup = Lookup(self.conn)
        self.data = {}

    def __get_conn(self, **credentials):
        return Connection(**credentials)

    def _get_averages(self, data):
        return {
            'mean' : numpy.mean(data),
            'median' : numpy.median(data)
        }

    def method1(self):
        conn = self.__get_conn()
        cursor = conn.get_cursor()
        data = cursor.execute(QUERY1)

        for row in data:
            # Logic specific to the results returned by the query.
            row['arg1'] = self._lookup.find_data_by_method_1(row)
            avgs = self._get_averages(row['data'])
            row['mean'] = avgs['mean']
            row['median'] = avgs['median']

        return data

    def method2(self):
        conn = self.__get_conn()
        cursor = conn.get_cursor()
        data = cursor.execute(QUERY2)

        for row in data:
            # Logic specific to the results returned by the query.
            row['arg2'] = self._lookup.find_data_by_method_2(row)
            avgs = self._get_averages(row['data'])
            row['mean'] = avgs['mean']
            row['median'] = avgs['median']

        return  data

    def lookup(self, arg):

        methods = {
            'arg1' : self.method1,
            'arg2' : self.method2
        }

        method = methods(arg)
        self.data[arg] = method()

    def lookup_args(self):
        return self._lookup.find_args()

    def do_something_with_data(self):
        print self.data

def main():

    creds = {
        'host':'host',
        'user':'postgres',
        'database':'mydatabase',
        'password':'mypassword'
    }
    reporter = Report(**creds)

    args = reporter.lookup_args()
    threads = []
    for arg in args:
        thread = Thread(target=reporter.lookup, args=(arg,))
        threads.append(thread)

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    reporter.do_something_with_data()
```

The imported `Connection` class is a simple wrapper around psycopg2 to facilitate cursor creation and connecting to multiple postgres databases.

The imported `Lookup` class accepts a `Connection` instance and is used to perform short queries to find relevant data that drastically decreases performance when incorporated into the larger query.

`data` that is accepted by the `_get_averages` example method is a list of `decimal.Decimal` objects.

When I run all threads simultaneously I get a segfault. If I run each thread independently the script finishes successfully.

Using `gdb` I find numpy to be the culprit:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffedc8c700 (LWP 10997)]
0x00007ffff2ac33b7 in sortCompare (a=0x2e956298, b=0x2e956390) at numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c:1045
1045    numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c: No such file or directory.
        in numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c
```

I'm aware of [this bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5961) with numpy, but that seems to only affect sorting lists containing both class instances and other numeric types. The objects in my lists are guaranteed to be `decimal.Decimal` instances. (Yes, I verified this).

What could cause `numpy` to cause a segfault when used inside of a thread, but behave as expected otherwise?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but if the list elements are `decimal.Decimal` then an array built from them will be `dtype=object`.  But I find it puzzling that the code is even trying access a `.c` source file.  That should happen only during a compile.

Comment: NumPy can and will fault in C code because it it mostly written in C with only a veneer of Python on top.

Comment: @msw Understood. What I don't understand is *why* it fails when multiple threads are running.